# Which CPAN modules should be installed for this script?

Tags: perl

If a Perl script contains

```
use vars qw($PROGNAME $VERSION);
use lib "/usr/nagios/libexec";
use utils qw(%ERRORS);
```

which CPAN modules should I then install?

`cpan utils` doesn't find anything.

**Update**

It is [this](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Security/VPN-Software/check_openvpn_pl/details) script I am trying to get to work.

**Solution**

```
yum install nagios-plugins-perl.x86_64
```

Comment: I believe the correct answer is: none. Except for "nagios" itself. `vars` (obsolete now according to docs) and `lib` are core, and it seems likely that `use libs` adds the path to `utils` for the subsequent `use utils` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `utils.pm` comes with Nagios.

Comment: Have a look at http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html#PERLPLUGIN

Comment: @simbabque: sorry, buyt now it gives a 404

Comment: @realtebo I suspect you are looking for https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html - took me a minute to google :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
use lib "/usr/nagios/libexec";
```

To

```
use lib "/usr/nagios/plugins"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to keep my own plugins separate from the default plugins I used the following approach.

```
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/nagios/plugins
$ cd /usr/local/nagios/
$ ln -s /usr/lib/nagios/plugins libexec
```

Now I can keep my own stash of version controlled plugins under `/usr/local/nagios/plugins` but they use the distribution's (14.04 in my case) `utils.pm`.